# How can I wait for certain output from a process then continue in Bash?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a bash script to do some stuff, start a process, wait for that process to say it's ready, and then do more stuff while that process continues to run. The issue I'm running into is finding a way to wait for that process to be ready before continuing, and allowing it to continue to run.

In my specific case I'm trying to setup a PPP connection. I need to wait until it has connected before I run the next command. I would also like to stop the script if PPP fails to connect. pppd prints to stdout.

In psuedo code what I want to do is:

```
[some stuff]
echo START

[set up the ppp connection]
pppd <options> /dev/ttyUSB0
while 1
  if output of pppd contains "Script /etc/ppp/ipv6-up finished (pid ####), status = 0x0"
    break
  if output of pppd contains "Sending requests timed out"
    exit 1

[more stuff, and pppd continues to run]
echo CONTINUING
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: per pppd man page '**Diagnostics**

Messages are sent to the syslog daemon using facility LOG_DAEMON. ... See the syslog(8) documentation for details of where the syslog daemon will write the messages. On most systems, the syslog daemon uses the /etc/syslog.conf file to specify the destination(s) for syslog messages. You may need to edit that file to suit.' .... Did you see what kind of messages appear in the syslog? You should be able to have your while loop scan the file, looking for newest mesgs. Good luck.

Answer (score 34):

I had to do something similar waiting for a line in /var/log/syslog to appear. This is what worked for me:

```
FILE_TO_WATCH=/var/log/syslog
SEARCH_PATTERN='file system mounted'

tail -f -n0 ${FILE_TO_WATCH} | grep -qe ${SEARCH_PATTERN}

if [ $? == 1 ]; then
    echo "Search terminated without finding the pattern"
fi
```

It pipes all new lines appended to the watched file to grep and instructs grep to exit quietly as soon as the pattern is discovered. The following if statement detects if the 'wait' terminated without finding the pattern.

Comment: On linux, prefixing the 'tail' command like this should do the trick to terminate after 10 seconds:
`timeout --signal=SIGINT 10 tail ...`. On Mac you will have to install it first with MacPorts or similar.

Comment: On Ubuntu doesn't work, first you have to pass `-n1` to get any output from tail, then grep won't actually quit when it gets a match because the pipe is still open I guess. Also instead of timeout you probably want the tail argument `--pid`.

Answer (score 6):

The quickest solution I came up with was to run pppd with nohup in the background and check the nobup.out file for stdout. It ended up something like this:

```
sudo nohup pppd [options] 2> /dev/null &
#  check to see if it started correctly
PPP_RESULT="unknown"
while true; do
  if [[ $PPP_RESULT != "unknown" ]]; then
    break
  fi
  sleep 1
  # read in the file containing the std out of the pppd command
  #  and look for the lines that tell us what happened
  while read line; do
    if [[ $line == Script\ /etc/ppp/ipv6-up\ finished* ]]; then
      echo "pppd has been successfully started"
      PPP_RESULT="success"
      break
    elif [[ $line == LCP:\ timeout\ sending\ Config-Requests ]]; then
      echo "pppd was unable to connect"
      PPP_RESULT="failed"
      break
    elif [[ $line == *is\ locked\ by\ pid* ]]; then
      echo "pppd is already running and has locked the serial port."
      PPP_RESULT="running"
      break;
    fi
  done < <( sudo cat ./nohup.out )
done
```

Comment: I didkn't know the construct `<( sudo cat ./nohup.out )`, here is an explanation: https://superuser.com/questions/1059781/what-exactly-is-in-bash-and-in-zsh

Answer (score 2):

There's a tool called "Expect" that does almost exactly what you want. More info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect

You might also take a look at the man pages for "chat", which is a pppd feature that does some of the stuff that expect can do.

Comment: expect is working, but how do I let expect exit and the spawned process (pppd) continue in the background?

Answer (score 0):

If you  go with `expect`, as @sblom advised, please check `autoexpect`.

You run what you need via `autoexpect` command and it will create `expect` script.
Check [man page](http://expect.sourceforge.net/example/autoexpect.man.html) for examples.