# How to wait for text in bash shell output?

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I'm executing a command in a bash shell and need to wait until a command echos a string. This is the pseudo code for what I have in mind. What do I set `currentline` to such that the `until` loop exits when `the text output I'm waiting for` echos?

```
currentline=""
until [[$currentline | grep -m 1 "the text output I'm waiting for"]]; do
  echo " == Waiting for the text == "
  currentline=??? 
  sleep 1;
done
```

**EDIT**: `the text output I'm waiting for` tells the script the executed command is ready to receive input. The command does not terminate after `the text output I'm waiting for`. I want the script to stop sleeping and continue.

**EDIT #2**: The script runs on a remote CI/CD service, Codemagic, so I don't think I can use `tail` or any command that needs the path to the log file? (As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197527/how-can-i-wait-for-certain-output-from-a-process-then-continue-in-bash))

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/23930217/12957340

Comment: I'd look into using expect instead.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to give an example of what you want to DO once that string is found in the command output and also state if you want to do that thing EVERY time the string occurs in the output or just the first time or something else.

Answer (score 2):

So just:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ "$line" == "the text .... " ]]; then
          break;
    fi
done < <(your-cmd)
```

if you want to keep your-cmd running, use coproc.

```
coproc your-cmd

while ..... as above ...
done <&"${COPROC[0]}"
```

Comment: Gah. Unfortunately I'm on a remote Mac Pro which doesn't support coproc

Comment: Then create two fifos and run the command in the background and remember to kill it when done.