# Getting a shell script to wait for a specific response from python program

Tags: python, shell

I'm trying to write a script that calls a python program, pauses until the program outputs a certain message (not when the program ends), then moves on.

If I have example.py like this that just runs indefinitely:

```py
doSomething()
print('I did something')
doSomethingElseForever()
```

I want to have a script something like this:

```sh
echo "Running python program"
python3 example.py &
waitForOutput("I did something")
echo "Python program did something, it's still running in the background"
doSomeMoreScriptStuff
```

Ideally, I would just run the script and it would launch example.py, pause until example.py output "I did something", then continue on to launch more programs or whatever, without stopping example.py (hence the &).

I'm working in Ubuntu BTW.

Edit: I think in my particular application at the moment I could just change my python script to create a file instead of print(), but for the sake of learning (and because that seems like a convoluted way to do things), let's assume I can't edit the python file. So all I have to work with is the known output of a print() statement.

Comment: I notice you added the [tag:python] tag, so are you open to solutions in Python? If so, the naive answer is just to break up the Python script, but that assumes `doSomething` and `doSomethingElseForever` don't have any mutual dependencies.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I wait for certain output from a process then continue in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197527/how-can-i-wait-for-certain-output-from-a-process-then-continue-in-bash)

Comment: I came across that post earlier, but I don't think that's quite what I'm looking for. The first answer isn't what I want, because (I think) it's checking for changes in a file, which isn't what I'm doing, the second answer might possibly work, but I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to utilize it in my context.  I can't separate doSomething() and doSomethingElseForever() unfortunately, since the message I'm actually looking for is a confirmation that an indefinitely running process has started.

Comment: Why don't you change your Python script so that it creates a file when it has done itts first thing? Then your shell script can simply wait till that file exists.

Comment: @Josh I think the top two answers together are saying that you can redirect the output of the process to a file then watch the output with `tail -f ... | grep -q ...`. Although I've never done anything like this myself. And just in case none of those solutions work for you, you can [edit] to explain how and highlight what's different about your situation.

Comment: I've edited my original question. Basically I'm just looking for a cleaner way to do things than creating a file as an output flag. Plus that solution would only work assuming I have control over the python script, which might not be the case in the future. I hope that helps clear up what I'm asking a bit.

Comment: Do you need to actually see - in your Terminal -  the output from the program you call?

Comment: No, it doesn't matter if I can visually see the output myself or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `pexpect`. I start a thread which calls `pexpect.spawn()` to run your child script. It waits for the output you want and then sets an event so the main program knows the event has occurrred. It then waits for the child to exit, which, in turn, allows the main program to exit:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pexpect
import time
import threading

doneIt = threading.Event()

def childHandler():
   """Spawns the child and manages its output"""
  
   global doneIt 
   print('HANDLER: Spawning child')
   child = pexpect.spawn('./example.sh')
   print('HANDLER: Child spawned, waiting for it to do something')
   child.expect('I did something')
   doneIt.set()
   print('HANDLER: Waiting for child to finish')
   child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
   print('HANDLER: Done')

if __name__ == "__main__":
   print('MAIN: Starting')
   cH = threading.Thread(target=childHandler)
   cH.start()

   # Wait for event and do other stuff, like printing
   while True:
      print('MAIN: waiting for child to do something')
      if doneIt.wait(1):
          break

   print('MAIN: Continuing...')

   # Wait till childHandler exits before exiting
   cH.join() 
   print('MAIN: Exit')
```

---

I used this `example.sh` as a mock-up of the Python script you call:

```
#!/bin/bash

LOG="run.txt"
date +'Running: %H:%M:%S' > "$LOG"
for ((i=8;i>0;i--)) ; do
  date +'Running: %H:%M:%S' >> "$LOG"
  sleep 1
done

date +'SUCCESS: %H:%M:%S' >> "$LOG"
echo "I did something"

for ((i=1;i<10;i++)) ; do
  date +'Continuing: %H:%M:%S' >> "$LOG"
  sleep 1
done

date +'DONE: %H:%M:%S' >> "$LOG"
```

And here is the log:

```
Running: 13:05:27
Running: 13:05:27
Running: 13:05:28
Running: 13:05:29
Running: 13:05:30
Running: 13:05:31
Running: 13:05:32
Running: 13:05:33
Running: 13:05:34
SUCCESS: 13:05:35
Continuing: 13:05:35
Continuing: 13:05:36
Continuing: 13:05:37
Continuing: 13:05:38
Continuing: 13:05:39
Continuing: 13:05:40
Continuing: 13:05:41
Continuing: 13:05:42
Continuing: 13:05:43
DONE: 13:05:44
```

Comment: I was hoping to do it in the script itself, but actually I don't see any reason that would necessarily be the case. I'll try out pexpect, it looks like that would work for what I'm trying to do.  Thank you