# Splitting batch script commands and execute separately with subprocess

Tags: python, scripting, subprocess

I am writing a Python script to automatically process 3D models with [Reality Capture](https://www.capturingreality.com/). Reality Capture offers [CLI processing](https://support.capturingreality.com/hc/en-us/articles/360010442279-What-is-Command-Line-Interface-CLI-) which I would like to execute via Python using the subprocess module.

The issue I am facing is with running separate commands without closing the program in between. Instead of running through a whole range of commands I would like to run just one command at a time in any order that is required on the active instance of the program.

In between running the specific program commands there will be some python code that checks the output logs of Reality Capture and decides which command to run next. Therefore just running a bunch of these commands in one go as shown in the example below is not an option:

```
:: run RealityCapture
"C:\\Program Files\\Capturing Reality\\RealityCapture\\RealityCapture.exe" ^
-addFolder "C:\RC_test\images" ^
-align ^
-setReconstructionRegionAuto ^
-save "C:\RC_test\rc_test_project.rcproj" ^
-quit
```

My goal is to open the program using Python but then let the user or Python program decide which command to run next. Opening the program would be a single command like:

```
call = "\"C:\Program Files\Capturing Reality\RealityCapture\RealityCapture.exe\""
result = subprocess.run(call, capture_output=True, text=True, shell=True)
```

If the next thing that is required is adding images from a folder I would then like to run something like this:

```
call = "-addFolder \"C:\RC_test\images\""
result = subprocess.run(call, capture_output=True, text=True, shell=True)
```

Unfortunately this does not work as the -addFolder needs to be added directly to the line of the program. For example this does work fine:

```
call = "\"C:\Program Files\Capturing Reality\RealityCapture\RealityCapture.exe\" -addFolder \"C:\RC_test\images\""
result = subprocess.run(call, capture_output=True, text=True, shell=True)
```

The problem with this is that this opens a new instance of Reality Capture and most of these commands require Reality Capture to have an open project file. If I run two different commands with subprocess using the snippet above it will open two instances of Reality Capture. So as a workaround I would need to run this for every command:

- Open the program
- Load the project
- Execute a the desired command
- Save the project
- Close the program

This of course results in a lot of overhead when running 50+ different commands. It would still be acceptable in the first few stages of the processing, however the later stages requires the loading of several GB large files attached to the project file which is not ideal doing 25x instead of once.

My question: Is there a way to execute the commands on the already open instance of the program? Is this possible or is this just a limitation of how batch CLI scripting works? The Google search gods have left me without answers unfortunately.

Comment: I don't really understand what you really want to do, nor whether the user is supposed to choose an option, or wait for some unknown reason till he is ready to do something, but I suspect you can do what you want with `pexpect`, example here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/70246072/2836621

Comment: Or maybe you just want `subprocess.run(["RealityCapture.exe", "-addFolder", "C:\somewhere", "-align", ... ])`

Comment: @MarkSetchell, I see why the question might be a bit confusing. I have attempted to better explain what I want to do based on your input.

Comment: Yes, `pexpect` should be good at that, try putting `[pexpect]` in the Search box at the top of this page.

Answer (score 0):

The CLI provided by Reality Capture seems to only accept commands for startup, not while it is running ([cf docs](https://support.capturingreality.com/hc/en-us/articles/360016556119-List-of-CLI-commands)).
The examples provided [there](https://www.capturingreality.com/realitycapture-cli-sample-scripts) seem to confirm that.
Taken from the `_ProcessAll.bat` of the `CalculateTextured3DModel` example :

```
%RealityCaptureExe% -addFolder %Images% ^
        -align ^
        -setReconstructionRegionAuto ^
        -calculateNormalModel ^
        -selectMarginalTriangles ^
        -removeSelectedTriangles ^
        -renameSelectedModel %ModelName% ^
        -calculateTexture ^
        -save %Project% ^
        -exportModel %ModelName% %Model% ^
        -quit
```

What you could do is use the [Builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) to separate gathering the user interactions from finally running Reality Capture once with all the parameters.
In other words :

```py
class Builder():
    ...

builder = Builder()
builder.load_project("path/to/savefile.rcproj")
builder.new_scene()
builder.add_image("image_name")
command = builder.build()
print(command)  # ['RealityCapture.exe', '-load', 'path/to/savefile.rcproj', ...]
subprocess.run(command)
```

It comes back to implementing a Python API for the CLI.

I recommend you always pass the `headless` and `stdConsole` parameters, they seem handy for your use case. For the style, I suggest to implement a [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).